# How to get dex file from apk when using v2 signature?

Tags: android, dex, smali, apktool

I hava an apk file.

When the apk is used v1 signature, it is ok when unzip an apk file. But when using v2, unzip fails.

How can i get the original dex file?

What i want to do is to modify the dex with ida, then rebuild to get a new apk.

I know i can use apktool to get smali files, then modify smali file and rebuild to a new apk.
But i want do try modify dex file in hex mode(eg. using ultra edit).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2KLe.png)

Comment: What zip tool do you use for unzipping? I have never experienced any problems unzipping an APK that has a v2 or v3 signature (e.g. via WinRAR, 7Zip, ..). Good luck with your hex modification try. Because of CRC32 values, central import method and string tables this is very complex. If you want to change more than a conditional jump to non-conditional apktool is the better alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I use 7zip to unzip my apk file. It shows me "Headers Error. Unconfirmed start of archive. Warning: There are some data after the end of the payload data.".
I use Android Studio of version 2020.3.1. Android gradle plugin version is 7.0.2. Gradle version is 7.0.2. CompileSdk version is 31. TargetSdk version is 31.
Use command 'gradlew assembleDebug' in command window(it requires jdk11). Then the apk build out will lead to unzip error.

Comment: But however, I click the 'Run app' button in the Android Studio. The generated apk can bu unzipped correctly. Use 'gradlew assembleDebug' in command window not.

Comment: Is the project really just a standard hello-world project? Z7ip opens up all created APK files without any problems (v19 and v21.05). May be you have a virus scanner installed that destroys the ZIP file?

Comment: https://github.com/xiaobo0113/TesetUnzip
This is the demo project. The situation shows up when you use 'gradlew assembleDebug' in the command window to build the project.

Comment: Just cloned the repo and tested the included `app-debug_unzip_error.apk` file. It can be unzipped without any problems by any ZIP tool I have.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use 7zip. Right click on the apk, then select 7-Zip->Extract here. Then I get error like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2KLe.png Maybe my computer has something wrong~ However, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `-s, --no-src` to apktool for `apktool -s name_of_apk.apk` and that will skip the sources. This is what is normally disassembled to smali folders.

https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/#decode